# Why the drastic performance increase WITH SCHEMABIND?

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization, user-defined-functions

I was running a complex query that taking 10 minutes or so to execute.

I tracked down a UDF that was regularly called & added WITH SCHEMABINDING to said function. Now the complex query takes seconds to run & I don't quite understand why. Can anybody explain where this incredible performance boost came from? Code for this simple UDF is below and again, I do use it quite a bit.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetMaxBatch]()
RETURNS INT with SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @max_batch INT
    SELECT @max_batch = max(batch) FROM dbo.map
    RETURN @max_batch;
END;
```

Since the UDF returns the same value within a session I just hardcoded the value and noticed that things ran really well. Started looking into the UDF itself and added schemabinding and that worked.

Comment: Version of SQL Server? Also is it just a `SELECT` or a write operation? And execution plans?

Comment: I'm using 2019 and, yes, the complex query just does a lot joins where the table/views being joined rely on this UDF to truncate the returned datasets. Sorry not savvy enough to talk about execution plans.

Comment: Just an aside... you could trim that down to RETURN (  select max(batch) from dbo.map )  ... assuming batch is an int.

Comment: In 2019 the difference could be inlining vs not inlined. And it only evaluating the `MAX` once when inlined instead of per row - but you need to look at the execution plans to see if there is anything in that

Comment: Thank you I'll try to spend some more time on the execution plan if that can tell me how many times a function is called ... just not super familiar with those.

Comment: Thx John that makes sense!

Comment: If it is inlined you should see a reference to `dbo.map` in the plan itself going into an aggregate operator, If it is not inlined there will just be a compute scalar with the function call

Comment: Maybe just the fact that you edited the function and forced a recompile? If you remove it again does it slow down?

Comment: Might give this a read: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/140381/is-there-any-benefit-to-schemabinding-a-function-beyond-halloween-protection

Comment: Side note: you can increase performance even more by using a Table Valued Function `CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetMaxBatch]() RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN SELECT max_batch = max(batch) FROM dbo.map;`

Comment: @Xedni - This function does data access so it is still not going to be marked as deterministic with or without schema binding